# jackson: how to unmarshal to a class using generics in runtime?

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson, runtime

I need to unmarshal a json string to a Class using generics in runtime. Something like:

```
String classname = "this.is.a.class.name.read.at.runtime";
Class cls = Class.forName(classname);
mapper.readValue(jsonPayload, new TypeReference<GenericClass<cls>>() {});
```

Obviously, the above way does not work and I am unable to find a good solution.

Comment: And `mapper.readValue(jsonPayload, cls);` does not work?

Comment: No, since my class is GenericClass<cls> , not cls.

Comment: So you are trying to unmarshal an instance of `TypeReference` which is parameterized with `GenericClass` which is parameterized with some type? If that is what you are trying to achieve then I don't think it is possible. The type information of a generic class is a compile time concept. But jackson needs the type information what to unmarshal into at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The following code solved my issue:

```
String genericParameterClassName = "this.is.a.class.name.read.at.runtime";
Class clazz = Class.forName(genericParameterClassName);
JavaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametrizedType(GenericClass.class,GenericClass.class,clazz);
GenericClass m = mapper.readValue(jsonPayload, type);
```